# Why jqgrid URL is invoked only one time?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, jqgrid

I have a javascript function in which i receive a value of drop down. function is below:

```
function SetTemplateId(id) // this method is called on drop down change event
{
      templateId=id;  // template id is global variable

      showjqgrid();  //this method show the Jqgrid
}
```

ShowJqgrid method is below

```
function showjqgrid()
{

$("#grid").jqGrid({
    datatype: 'json',
    url: '/Home/DynamicGridData?id='+templateId,

........
}
```

jqgrid is works fine but the problem is when "setTemplateid" function is called first time it works fine and data is show correctly and after first time when i change drop down value the "setTemplateId" function is called(i checked by alert()) and showgrid is also called but the URL is not invoked. If i destroy jqgrid in "setTemplateId" function then jqgrid is not shownn. If i reload jqgrid then also the data show only first time. I debuged it. Only first time action method is called. After that its not called. What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is very easy. The function `showjqgrid` convert empty table `<table id="grid"></table>` in relatively complex structure of divs and tables. After that jqGrid makes request to the `url`.

So you have two main options (alternatives) to fix the problem:

- include call of `GridUnload` method as the first line of `showjqgrid`. It will destroy the complex structure of divs and tables created previously and reduce there to one empty `<table>`.
- you can create grid **once**. On the next time you should update `url` parameter using `setGridParam` and then trigger `reloadGrid` which will update the content of the grid holding the outer part unchanged.

Additionally I would recommend you to read [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2928819/315935) which shown how to use `postData` parameter of jqGrid where the properties are defined as functions. I suppose that `templateId` which you use as the value of `id` parameter of `url` will be evaluated in some way inside of dropdown change event. So you can consider to do this inside of the function defined inside of `postData.id`. In the case you could use `url: '/Home/DynamicGridData` and the part `?id='+templateId` will be appended by jqGrid.

Comment: Kindly give example of setGridParam.  I will try this all later because due to some reason my visual studio is crashed.

Comment: @Hiba: `$("#grid").jqGrid("setGridParam", {url: newUrl});`. Alternatively you can get **reference** to all jqGrid parameters by usage of `var p = $("#grid").jqGrid("getGridParam");` After that you can change the `url` using the code like `p.url = newUrl;`. No call of `setGridParam` will be required.

Comment: It works . But if loadonce is false. Thanks again Oleg. You always help in jqgrid questions. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Hiba: If you use `loadonce: true` and you want to reload the data from the *server* then you need just reset `datatype` to `"json"` **before** reloading the grid (`$("#grid").jqGrid("setGridParam", {url: newUrl, dytatype: "json"}).trigger("reloadGrid");` or `var p = $("#grid").jqGrid("getGridParam"); p.url = newUrl; p.dytatype = "json"; $("#grid").trigger("reloadGrid");`). So all works in the same way. You need just know that jqGrid changes `datatype` to `"local"` after the first loading from the server.